# Get Non-Error HTTP Status Code Response in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, http-status-codes, webviewclient

Our app returns an arbitrary code (202) when the user needs to complete two-factor authentication for their account login. On iOS, we can receive this code via the `WKNavigationDelegate` and present the user with the 2FA screen. However, on Android, we can't seem to find a method which will give us a non-error HTTP status code for the `WebView`. The only methods we're aware of are `onReceivedError()` and `onReceivedHttpError()` which only get called for codes >= 400.

Is there a way to get HTTP status codes < 400 for a `WebView` i.e. 200, 202, 302, 304, etc?